# Regarding scope and an instance variable "never being assigned to"

Tags: c#, scope

First class is called `EvenBetterValueList` (public):

```
ValueList _valueList;

public override void AppendAdditionalMenuItems(ToolStripDropDown menu){
    // Stuff
}

private void Menu_MyCustomItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e){
    // Stuff
}

protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA){
    // firstList and secondList list<string> declaration
    ValueList _valueList = new ValueList(firstList, secondList);
}
```

Second class is called `ValueList` (as you can tell in my SolveInstance method. This too is public):

The skeleton is:

```
    private List<string> _firstList = new List<string>();
    private List<string> _secondList = new List<string>();

    // .. getter setters

    public ValueList(List<string> firstList, List<string> secondList) {
        _firstList.Clear();
        _secondList.Clear();

        // Add vars to global vars

        _firstList.AddRange(firstList);
        _secondList.AddRange(secondList);
    }
```

With this, I was planning on adding a private variable in the class to extend my class scope, however this happened:

[image]

It appears `_valueList` is never assigned to.

Could this be a scope issue again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SolveInstance` function is making its very own instance of `ValueList` that coincidentally has the same name as your member variable `_valueList`.

Don't re-declare it in that function.

```
protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
{
    // firstList and secondList list<string> declaration
    _valueList = new ValueList(firstList, secondList);
}
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! I can't believe I didn't think of this!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
ValueList _valueList;
```

Try:

```
ValueList _valueList = new ValueList();
```

When you don't call the default constructor nothing gets assigned.

By pre-assigning all your properties there is an automatic default constructor.  If you don't pre-assign them all build a default constructor that assigns default values to the properties that aren't pre-assigned.

Comment: Hmm. My `ValueList()` constructor takes in two arguments.

Comment: I added more explanation.